# Successive AJAX calls add an extra consecutive call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a pretty standard ajax call for a live update, however, say I call the the ajax, everything is good, but say I want to call it again, this time, I will get **2 calls**, and if I try again then I'll have 3, I can verify this by invoking and alert and with the Network DevCon of Chrome, any idea why this is happening?

P.S: I'm using Laravel 5.1

```
$('button[name=act]').click(function() {
    var icon = $(this).closest('div.thumbnail').find('i');

    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        icon.show();
    });

    $("form").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/acttdb",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, status, jqXhr) {
                $(icon).fadeIn(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('fa-spinner fa-spin').addClass('fa-check text-success').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('fa-check text-success').addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
                    });
                });
            }/*,
               error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log("Error response:", jqXhr.responseText);
               }*/
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your brackets aren't balanced.

Comment: Actually, they are, but thanks I didn't notice on the paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are rebinding the submit event function every time the button is clicked which results in multiple copies of the function. Just move it out of the click even, and if you want to force a submit on a click, you can call the submit() function with no parameters to fire the event.

Try the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('button[name=act]').click(function(){
        var icon = $(this).closest('div.thumbnail').find('i');

        $(document).ajaxStart(function()
        {
            icon.show();
        });

        $("form").submit(); //This submits the form on click
    });

    //This binds the function, so it should only be called once.
    $("form").submit(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/acttdb",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, status, jqXhr)
            {
                //BLAH
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I noticed two other things you might want to address. You want to somehow update the icon after it is loaded. You will need to have some other way to find the icon inside of the success function (possibly looking at the data that came back could yield some information that could be useful. Since it is json, it should be easy to update.)

Also, the way you currently have it will bind to all forms on the page. In the event that you have multiple forms on the page, you will probably want to change the selector to use an id.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This made me realize I was over complicating stuff and I didn't require the button.click function, I could find the icons easily since the form is the top DOM, and instead of going up from the button to the form and then going down, I just have to call $(this) and go down twice, thanks again!

Comment: I also have 2 more buttons, but I only needed the act one since I'm ajax'ing an img and the other 2 just update a column so the FormData isn't needed, so 1 type submit and 2 type buttons :).

Comment: Glad it helped. One design I've seen where multiple loading icons could be shown, but only one will be active at a time is to add a class to group all the icons together, the you apply your "loading" class to the one that is loading, and then when you are done, you just select them all and remove the loading class (jQuery won't complain if you remove the class and it doesn't exist.

Comment: One other option is to create a loading icon for the whole page and use the ajaxBefore send to show the icon whenever a new ajax call goes out. 

You can then bind the hide logic handler to the ajaxStop event which will fire after all ajax calls have completed.

Comment: This is what I've just finished! It's funny because I'm reading and you're suggesting what I just did, I'm using beforeSend and complete, and I'm using an icon with changing classes, I finished my live uploader and it works perfectly, however I can't use 1 icon because there are many forms (it's for a beachwear store) so they could update many sets in 1 go, but as of now it's finished.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that every time you click on the `act` button you call `$("form").submit(), which adds another`submit`handler to the form. So if you click on the`act` button 3 times, and then click on the form's submit button, it will send 3 AJAX requests.

It's almost always wrong to bind one event handler inside another event handler, you should bind all the event handlers at top level.

```
var icon;

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    if (icon) {
        icon.show();
    }
});

$('button[name=act]').click(function() {
    icon = $(this).closest('div.thumbnail').find('i');
});

$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/acttdb",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data, status, jqXhr) {
            if (icon) {
                icon.fadeIn(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('fa-spinner fa-spin').addClass('fa-check text-success').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('fa-check text-success').addClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
                    });
                });
            }
        }/*,
           error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log("Error response:", jqXhr.responseText);
           }*/
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a good answer but techdude helped me the most, thanks a lot anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Based in incremental calls and my guessings, I have to say that you're printing this code each time you make the (ajax) call, leading to bind your `form` element again in each call.. 
Am I right?

JO.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code, it's fixed now; The ajax is called when I click the submit button, after that I make a call for when the form is submitted, I prevent that submit and THEN call the ajax.